# Merge the pipes: [ipc] and [interprocess]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

We should merge [interprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interprocess) into [ipc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipc). Their tag wikis are very similar:

- [interprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interprocess)

  > A capability supported by some operating systems that allows one process to communicate with another process. The processes can be running on the same computer or on different computers connected through a network.
  > It enables one application to control another application, and for several applications to share the same data without interfering with one another.
- [ipc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipc)

  > IPC stands for Inter-process Communication and represents a set of methods for exchanging data and messages between threads and processes.